# How to vertically center text in a <span>?

Tags: html, css

How can I vertically center text that is wrapped in a `<span>`? The `<span>` must have `min-height` of `45px`. Here is what I am envisioning:

```
--------                  -------
text

                --->      text   


--------                  -------
```

I tried `vertical-align` as well as methods from this [article](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/). None of them worked

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Try using [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), all modern browsers support it, with [prefixes](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) it also works in IE10.

```css
span {
  min-height: 100px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
}
```

```html
<span>vertical center</span>
```

Comment: It breaks with text-overflow

Answer (score 12):

While you are using span, you could simply change the display method to `table-cell`. Remember, if you are going to use div instead of span, you might need to use another way.

```css
span {
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span>text</span>
```

Answer (score 10):

The "old" way to do this, if you need true support for old browsers (that is IE6 & IE7), is to use `line-height`. This method only allows 1 line of text.

```css
span {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<span>vertical center</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve vertical center text alignment by any of the below approaches based upon which browser your application is going to support.

`<span class="vertical-center">Center Text</span>`

1) using display: inline-flex; (if you are targeting mordern browsers like Chrome, safari, IE11 and above you can go with flex)
Check: Can I use https://caniuse.com/#search=inline-flex

```
.vertical-center {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

2) Using display: table-cell; (if you are targeting older browsers too like IE9, go with second approach )

```
.vertical-center-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/prakashup/mcgzLfkn/8/)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to align your text inside the span element both horizontally and vertically you can also try the `inline-grid` display.

```
span {
display: inline-grid;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
}

<span>vertically and horizontally centered text spanning over more than just one line</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
span{
height: 45px;
display: grid;
align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

span is set to display inline and the example you linked to should work with divs that are set to display block. Trying adding display block to your span and then following the advice in the link. Combining them should get it to work.
But then, why use a span?

Comment: @Alex So are lots of block elements. `<p>` springs to mind first.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="image.jpg">
  <p>Text goes here</p>
</div>


.container img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.container p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 10px; /* adjust as needed */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To vertically center text in a `span` element, you can use CSS flexbox. Here's an example:

```html
<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* vertically center items */
    justify-content: center; /* horizontally center items */
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <span>Vertically centered text</span>
</div>
```

In this example, we create a container `div` with a height of `100px` and a border of `1px` to visualize the centering. We then use `display: flex` to enable flexbox layout, and set `align-items: center` to center items vertically and `justify-content: center` to center items horizontally. Finally, we place the `span` element inside the container.

This will vertically center the text in the `span` element inside the container.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the other answers on this page to implement a single-word button as a span with border.

But for some reason I could not get the text inside the span to be the exact same distance from both top- and bottom- borders. So it did not look quite right. Setting "padding: 0px;" did not help.

Putting the button-label inside an inner span and moving it up 1px with relative positioning fixed the problem:

```
<span>  
  <span
   style=" position : relative;
           top      : -1px;
         "
  >MY BUTTON 
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Try setting the line height to the same value as your font size. Having those values mismatch can cause the text to be shifted a few pixels to the bottom, which is what your -1px top position seems to "fix".